# How to implement HMVC in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, hmvc

Does laravel 4 have built in support for hmvc or are there bundles for this functionality? What is the best way to use HMVC in laravel 4.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/hmvc

Comment: Just noticed that bundle is for Laravel 3. It's not been updated on [Github](https://github.com/kbanman/laravel-hmvc) for about a year. I've found this http://docs.cartalyst.com/api which looks like an option if you are willing to pay.

Comment: Generally HMVC normally means you need to refactor whatever it is you're doing. If code in a controller needs to be called from multiple controllers then abstract it out into a service or model. Of course, without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve it's hard to say if this will apply to you.

Answer (score 5):

This tutorial shows you how to implement modules in laravel 4 http://creolab.hr/2013/05/modules-in-laravel-4/

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more hmvc option, https://github.com/LevareCMS/modulemanager

If you come from codeigniter, you may like this, http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8664

Also is worth mentioning, depending on your needs, a [view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers) may achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It was implemented with laravel 4 in HMVC. You can clone at: https://github.com/ReyzWB/Laravel-4-Modular-Approach